# How to use ShowFileDialog in Console Application c#

Tags: c#

How can I assign filepath to the string `file123` using `ShowFileDialog();`

```cs
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(file123).ToList();
foreach(string line in lines)
{
   Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We need to see more about what file123 is and what you'd like it to be. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need.

first Add

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

to your console project;

then you need to mark

```
[STAThread]
```

above your main method.

and tested code below

```
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xyz = string.Empty;
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            DialogResult result = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                xyz = openFileDialog.FileName;


            Console.WriteLine(xyz);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to add a refrence to System.Windows.Forms.dll for this to work

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms; // Required to use OpenFileDialog.
using System.IO;            // Required to read/write to files.

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread] // This attribute is required to access OLE related functions.
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.Multiselect = false;
            string file123 = "";
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            { file123 = openFileDialog1.FileName; }
            List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(file123).ToList();
            foreach (string line in lines)
            { Console.WriteLine(line); }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```